Microsoft Excel Search and Replace phrases in two columns based on a list in the same sheet

I'm trying to find a way to search and replace multiple words in a source column based on a list of references in the same sheet. I've seen other threads that deal with a very similar problem only the difference is I want to be able to use the (*) function to find and replace phrases instead of just words.
Based on the sample, I want to take the content from A2 and get a result in B2 based on the list from columns D and E.
Example:
Take this content - Measuring 1L x 1W x 1H inches and weighing 1 lbs, the blue case is the perfect accessory to your new phone
And end up with just - Measuring 1L x 1W x 1H inches and weighing 1 lbs.
Basically replacing everything that came after "lbs" (lbs*) and replace them with a period to end the sentence.
In actual application the words differ from content to content but generally they follow a pattern so I want to be able to use (*) function.
Thanks in advance!
As per the sample image, column B has the formula =SUBSTITUTE function but again, I find it only works to change one word into another word.
Would like to be able to target a string of words or a phrase that follow a pattern and replace them with another phrase or a single word.

Please include more than one example and expected output as a markdown table.  As well as an example of the reference column.

Hi Scott. I've updated the sample image to show exactly what I'd like to end up with. There are three rows as references.

Be careful with character searches that may be embedded in other words: "LBS" is in "Bulbs", you can also use multiple SUBSTITUTE in one formula

Please, as was mentioned before, post your sample data as a markdown table.  A screenshot limits its use to those who are willing to spend time laboriously retyping it into a spreasheet. Read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

respectively, * collectively becomes respectively, collectively and inches respectively, becomes inches,. This means that you third example will not result in your expected outcome. because inches respectively [..] collectively becomes inches respectively, collectively and inches respectively, collectively becomes inches, 

Here's a quick draft. Regular expression is more suitable for this task, but will try to use wild card with SEARCH first.

As Jan commented, we don't want to replace lbs in bulbs - I have not addressed it
Adjustments made to the input to avoid extra handling

first entry: lbs > lbs**




Order of old string is important: the more specific ones need to be replaced first. To avoid further steps, I have manually placed inches and weighing above inches and weigh.



Using Microsoft 365,

Wild card matches with wild card at the end need to be applied last, so sort the list (wild_index and old_new_sorted)
Adding weights to sort by is another option
Find the start and end positions using SEARCH (case-insensitive, wild card match) to use with REPLACE; to find the end position, reverse the strings
REDUCE is used to apply multiple substitutions

=LET(
    src, A2:A4,
    old_new, C2:D14,
    indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(old_new)),
    wild_index, IF(
        RIGHT(INDEX(old_new, , 1)) = "*",
        MAX(indices) + 1,
        indices
    ),
    old_new_sorted, SORTBY(old_new, wild_index),
    revStr, LAMBDA(str,
        TEXTJOIN("", 1, MID(str, SEQUENCE(LEN(str), , LEN(str), -1), 1))
    ),
    match_end, LAMBDA(find, within,
        LEN(within) - SEARCH(revStr(find), revStr(within)) + 1
    ),
    repl_wild, LAMBDA(inStr,
        REDUCE(
            inStr,
            indices,
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                LET(
                    start, SEARCH(INDEX(old_new_sorted, cur, 1), acc),
                    end, match_end(INDEX(old_new_sorted, cur, 1), acc),
                    IF(
                        ISNUMBER(start) * ISNUMBER(end),
                        REPLACE(
                            acc,
                            start,
                            end - start + 1,
                            INDEX(old_new_sorted, cur, 2)
                        ),
                        acc
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK("Result", MAP(src, repl_wild))
)



With REGEXREPLACE
Specifying old strings as regular expressions:

for example, lbs items can be condensed to this one with look behind assertion (to avoid replacing bulbs)
(?<=\d) lbs[., ]?.*

As suggested by Ron, consider surrounding lbs with word boundaries (\blbs\b) instead of look-behind option if required



=LET(
    src, A2:A4,
    old_new, C2:D9,
    indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(old_new)),
    repl_wild, LAMBDA(inStr,
        REDUCE(
            inStr,
            indices,
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                REGEXREPLACE(
                    acc,
                    INDEX(old_new, cur, 1),
                    INDEX(old_new, cur, 2)
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK("Result", MAP(src, repl_wild))
)



you can differentiate lbs from bulbs by using the word boundary token (\blbs) before and possibly after.

Thank you very much Ron! I used looking behind for \d as an example based on the given strings. I'll add your suggestion to my answer.

Nice crafted solution.
